# "Can" and "be able to"

Tags: can-modal

https://poligo.com/ja/node/4096

I'm confused with the explanation on the website.  It says that when you talk about ability, both "can" and "be able to" are OK, and that the following two sentences convey the same meaning.

A1) "Can you ride a bike?"

A2) "Are you able to ride a bike?"

However, it also says that you use "can" instead of "be able to" when you mean "know how to" and that the following sentences mean slightly different.

B1) "Can you cook?"

B2) "Are you able to cook?"

Why do B1 and B2 mean differently though A1 and A2 the same?  Sounds contradictory to me.  Why is B2 asking your situation, not your ability, while A2 is asking your ability?

Comment: I don't know how we can improve on the very clear explanation given by the website you link to. B2 asks whether the person will be free and willing to cook a meal on a particular occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main difference here is that the ability to ride a bike is well defined - either you can or you can't, however the ability to cook is rather less well defined.  Also the nature of the question is slightly different - in A1,2 the question asks whether you can conceptually ride, and doesn't suggest that there isn't a bike immediately on hand to be ridden.  B1,2 read as though one might be asked to cook if the answer is affirmative.  Consider what would happen if you added A3 "Would you please ride a bike" and B3 "Would you please cook".  I think that A3 is quite different from A1,2 while B3 is not so different from B1,2.